# SQLServer Select "invalid column name" but column exists

Tags: sql-server-2008

This is probably simple, but I'm completely stumped.  Its my first venture into SQLSever and I have a simple query as follows...

```
SELECT
    c.ClientID,
    c.FirstName,
    c.LastName,
    FORMAT(pm.date, 'd', 'en-US'),
    'Payment' AS 'Description',
    FORMAT(0, 'C', 'en-US') AS 'Fee',
    FORMAT(pm.amount, 'C', 'en-US') AS 'Paid',
    'WIP' AS 'Payment Type' 
FROM dbo.payments_made pm
LEFT JOIN dbo.clients c
    ON c.ID = pm.ClientID
LEFT JOIN dbo.payment_types pt
    ON pm.PaymentType = pt.ID
WHERE pm.business = 7
```

When I execute this query I get the following:

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVKXK.jpg)
However, looking at the table definitions, the ClientID column actually exists.  See here....

[Table Definitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYnVi.jpg)

I'm stumped as to what is happening.  Should be very simple.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Read the answer below.  The `ClientID` column exists in the `payments_made` table, _not_ the `clients` table.  In the `clients` table, the matching column is `ID`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ClientID is in the payments made table in the client table it is just named ID (based off your join)

You need to change the ClientID to ID or change c.  to pm.

so:

```
SELECT c.ID
// or 
SELECT pm.ClientID
```

Comment: Wow, sometimes I think that I'm too close to the trees to even see the branches.  :-)  Thanks so much.  I had been looking so hard at the wrong spots in the SQL.  A bit embarrassing, but I appreciate it!